# multiconditional mapping in python pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas, mapping

I am looking for a way to do some conditional mapping using multiple comparisons.

I have millions and millions of rows that I am investigating using sample SQL extracts in pandas. Along with SQL extracts read into pandas DataFrames I also have some rules tables, each with a few columns (these are also loaded into dateframes).

This is what I want to do: where a row in my SQL extract matches the conditions expressed in any one row in my rules table, I would like to generate a 1, else: 0. In the end I would like to add a column to my SQL extract called Rule Result with either 1's and 0's.

I have got a system that works using df.merge, but it produces many many extra duplicate rows in the process that must then be removed afterwards. I am looking for a better, faster, more elegant solution and would be grateful for any suggestions.

Here is a working example of the problem and the current solution code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

#Create a set of test data
test_df = pd.DataFrame()
test_df['A']   = [1,120,982,1568,29,455,None, None, None]
test_df['B']   = ['EU','US',None, 'GB','DE','EU','US', 'GB',None]
test_df['C']   = [1111,1121,1111,1821,1131,1111,1121,1821,1723]
test_df['C_C'] = test_df['C']

test_df
```

[test_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO9he.png)

```
#Create a rules_table
rules_df = pd.DataFrame()
rules_df['A_MIN'] = [0,500,None,600,200]
rules_df['A_MAX'] = [10,1000,500,1200,800]
rules_df['B_B']   = ['GB','GB','US','EU','EU']
rules_df['C_C']   = [1111,1821,1111,1111,None]

rules_df

def map_rules_to_df(df,rules):

    #create  column that mimics the index to keep track of later duplication
    df['IND'] = df.index

    #merge the rules with the data on C values
    df = df.merge(rules,left_on='C_C',right_on='C_C',how='left')

    #create a rule_result_column with a default value of zero
    df['RULE_RESULT']=0

    #create a mask indentifying those test_df_rows that fit with a    
    # rule_df_row
    mask = df[
        ((df['A'] > df['A_MIN']) | (df['A_MIN'].isnull())) &
        ((df['A'] < df['A_MAX']) | (df['A_MAX'].isnull())) &
        ((df['B'] == df['B_B'])  | (df['B_B'].isnull())) &
        ((df['C'] == df['C_C'])  | (df['C_C'].isnull()))
        ]

    #use mask.index to replace 0's in the result column with a 1
    df.loc[mask.index.tolist(),'RULE_RESULT']=1

    #drop the redundant rule_df columns
    df = df.drop(['B_B','C_C','A_MIN','A_MAX'],axis=1)

    #drop duplicate rows
    df = df.drop_duplicates(keep='first')

    #drop rows where the original index is duplicated and the rule result
    #is zero
    df = df[(df['IND'].duplicated(keep=False)) & (df['RULE_RESULT']==0) == False]

    #reset the df index with the original index
    df.index = df['IND'].values

    #drop the now redundant second index column (IND)
    df = df.drop('IND', axis=1)

    print('df shape',df.shape)

    return df

#map the rules
result_df = map_rules_to_df(test_df,rules_df)
result_df
```

[result_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvuGe.png)

I hope I have made what I would like to do clear and thank you for your help.

PS, my rep is non-existent, so i was not allowed to post more than two supporting images.